# how to change the anchor tags and headings in ckeditor by clicking remove format option in ckeditor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, ckeditor

In CKEditor-4 plugin by clicking the Remove Format option we Can't able to remove the headings1 to 6 as well as the anchor tag.. i want to remove those headings and anchor tags in ckedior where i want to change in ckeditor.js

Answer (score 0):

Try change line in your config.js of CKEditor like this:

```
config.format_tags = 'p;pre';
```

Comment: Its solution for both removing headings and anchor tags dude??

Comment: Just try it and ask only if it doesnot work as expected please.

Comment: It will restrict the headings and anchor tag..but need is if you are typed the headings 1 tag then we you don't need that text as heading1 then you will select the text then click remove format option then it will correct as normal text dude